# How to combine JSON objects and unnest array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch, push

I'm trying to fetch apis and combine the json objects into a single variable array that I can loop through.

using .push my variable array ends up as..

```
[
  [
    {"a":"1"}
  ],
  [
    {"b":"2"}
  ]
]
```

when i want this..

```
[
    {"a":"1"},
    {"b":"2"}
]
```

Here's my trimmed down code..

```
var combinedJson = [];

const r1 = fetch(firstJson).then(response => response.json());
const r2 = fetch(secondJson).then(response => response.json());

Promise.all([r1, r2])
  .then(([d1, d2]) => {
    combinedJson.push(d1, d2);
    console.log(combinedJson);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: `.then(([[d1], [d2]]) => `

Comment: i'm sorry what syntax is this? `{"a","1"}`?

Comment: @ITgoldman the wrong syntax.. edited.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Tried it, ty, but it's just returning the first entry from each JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what `Array.flat` does, but I like to use the spread `...` operator to spread arrays so then I can join them again.

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "a": "1"
}]

var arr2 = [{
  "b": "2"
}]

var combined = [...arr1, ...arr2]
console.log(combined)
```

Comment: Spread operators worked, thankyou very much. I'll play around again with array.flat and report back (have tried now and earlier but couldn't figure it out).

Comment: `combined = combined.flat();` worked as well. Ty again.